# Sending PNGs via PHP web to an Android App

Tags: java, php, android, png

What's the best way to pass a PNG image from PHP to an Android App in Java?

I tried in PHP:

```
$archi=file_get_contents("bar.png");
$archi2=base64_encode($archi);
print($archi2);
```

And in Java:

```
String img= Base64.decode(str);
byte[] byteArray = img.getBytes();
Bitmap myBitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray,0,byteArray.length);
```

But I always get:

SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null

Comment: You can encode the image in base64 then send it via JSON to Android.

Comment: Use Picasso library to load the png url directly to the ImageView.

Comment: I already tried to base64_encode it and print it, and then base64_decode on Android, and use BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray to get the PNG image, but I always get: "SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null". I noticed the base64_encoded bytes have the same lenght than the original, but the decoded byteArray have a different size

Comment: "best" is subjective... you should reword your question. Also, add some code to make the question more suitable for this forum (something like, "I tried this code - and post your code - but it is not working and here is the error I get")

Answer (score 1):

Solved, it was de Base64 decoding to String and then to ByteArray. Decoding directly to ByteArray using the following class worked:

Class:
https://grizzly.java.net/docs/2.3/xref/org/glassfish/grizzly/http/util/Base64Utils.html

Java Code:

```
byte[] bytea = Base64.decode(downloadedStr);
imagen=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytea,0,bytea.length);
```